# Javascript code Cookie to retain/keep alternative Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

Can any help
I have created a site but needed to know how to keep the users choice on which css they want to use.
i think i need to use cookies but im not 100% sure

Here is my index page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Internet Privacy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" title="Standard">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/AStyles.css" title="wacky" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeCSS(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) {
            var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);

            var newlink = document.createElement("link");
            newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            newlink.setAttribute("href", cssFile);

            document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
        }
        document.cookie="CSS="
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main_wrapper">
        <div class="header_wrapper">
        <!-- This the Logo and Banner Links-->
        <a href="index.php"><img id="logo" src="images/Logo.jpg" height="200" width="350"></a>
        <a href="http://www.wlv.ac.uk"><img id="banner" src="images/wlvLogo.gif" height="200" width="650">
        </div>
            <div class="menubar">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <!-- This is the Menubar that contains links to the various other pages-->
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">Privacy Laws</a></li>
                    <li><a href="procon.html">Pros and Cons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="wfa.html">Fights for Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content_wrapper">
            <!-- This is the Sidebar -->
                <div class="text">
                <h2>I have created this website for my first assignment.<br>This website is about how private the internet and how companies collect data, and how the data is used.</h2><br>
                <img id="indeximg" src="images/privacy.jpg" height="200" width="500">
                <br><p>Change Css Here <br> 
                <a href="#" onclick="changeCSS('styles/styles.css', 0);">Style 1</a> <br> 
                <a href="#" onclick="changeCSS('styles/AStyles.css', 0);">Style 2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="footer"><!-- This is the footer and it will be at the bottom of the page --> 
        <br><p>The website was created by Vincent Priestley at The University of Wolverhampton 2015</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If anyone can help, any help will be greatly appreciated

THank you in advance
Vinni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mate, I am not quite sure what's your requirement, 
but generally speaking, if you want store use's info, it should not be done on the front end, I mean cookie, local storage...

for saving use's info, you need database(or even file) and server side language to do it, like php+my-sql, asp.mvc+sql...

doing it using cookie or any other front end tech is not good,anyway...

Comment: ah ok, its just i have to only use html, i guess im gonna have to create a seperate webpage for each one on my site for the different css

Comment: @vincent, if you limited to do only html, i think you are right, there is no much place you can play,  tick my answer and happy coding bro!